# Preprocessing error in code comments

Tags: ocaml, camlp4

I got this error when compiling my code with `corebuild`:

```
~/project $ corebuild debug.byte
ocamlfind ocamldep -syntax camlp4o -package bin_prot.syntax -package sexplib.syntax,comparelib.syntax,fieldslib.syntax,variantslib.syntax -package core -modules globals.ml > globals.ml.depends
+ ocamlfind ocamldep -syntax camlp4o -package bin_prot.syntax -package sexplib.syntax,comparelib.syntax,fieldslib.syntax,variantslib.syntax -package core -modules globals.ml > globals.ml.depends
File "globals.ml", line 744, characters 57-17803 (end at line 1402, character 0):
Quotation not terminated
Preprocessing error on file globals.ml
Error while running external preprocessor
Command line: camlp4 '-I' '/Users/mapleleaf/.opam/4.01.0dev+trunk/lib/ocaml/camlp4' '-I' '/Users/mapleleaf/.opam/4.01.0dev+trunk/lib/type_conv' '-I' '/Users/mapleleaf/.opam/4.01.0dev+trunk/lib/ocaml' '-I\
' '/Users/mapleleaf/.opam/4.01.0dev+trunk/lib/ocaml' '-I' '/Users/mapleleaf/.opam/4.01.0dev+trunk/lib/bin_prot' '-I' '/Users/mapleleaf/.opam/4.01.0dev+trunk/lib/bin_prot' '-I' '/Users/mapleleaf/.opam/4.0\
1.0dev+trunk/lib/ocaml' '-I' '/Users/mapleleaf/.opam/4.01.0dev+trunk/lib/num' '-I' '/Users/mapleleaf/.opam/4.01.0dev+trunk/lib/sexplib' '-I' '/Users/mapleleaf/.opam/4.01.0dev+trunk/lib/sexplib' '-I' '/Us\
ers/mapleleaf/.opam/4.01.0dev+trunk/lib/comparelib' '-I' '/Users/mapleleaf/.opam/4.01.0dev+trunk/lib/comparelib' '-I' '/Users/mapleleaf/.opam/4.01.0dev+trunk/lib/fieldslib' '-I' '/Users/mapleleaf/.opam/4\
.01.0dev+trunk/lib/fieldslib' '-I' '/Users/mapleleaf/.opam/4.01.0dev+trunk/lib/variantslib' '-I
```

The offending line is this:

```
let allow_imm_inv = ref true (* imm inv to add of form @M<:v<:@A *)
```

How is this possible? I thought camlp4 is supposed to ignore quotation symbols in code comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CamlP4 does not "ignore" commented quotations. They must be balanced even in comments.

It is just like OCaml requires string quotes balanced in comments. For example:

```
(* " *)        <-  rejected as a syntax error
```

is rejected as a syntax error. It may sound strange but is useful to easily comment out strings like " *) ":

```
(* " *) " *)   <-  a valid comment (the syntax highlight gone crazy though)
```

In your example the same thing happens but for a P4 quotation `<:XXX< >>`. Fix is easy. Use white space like:

```
(* @M <: v <: @A *)
```

Comment: Thanks! I read about how camlp4 parses source code AND comments here: https://realworldocaml.org/beta3/en/html/the-compiler-frontend-parsing-and-type-checking.html#generating-documentation-from-interfaces. That's how ocamldoc generates documentation from comments like javadoc.